# angularjs custom confirm box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I'm trying to implement a custom confirm box using Angular. Ideally, I would simply like to add an attribute to enable the functionality. Example:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="delete(foo)">Delete</button>  ->  <button type="button" ng-click="delete(foo)" ng-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this foo?">Delete</button>
```

(foo is inside an ng-repeat... foo in fooList..)

So all of the problems I am having revolve around tying the click event that would normally happen to a different button. I have a seperate directive "confirmBox" that will create my modal (not using bootstrap) and handle all of the showing/hiding/etc.

What I am currently using requires me to alter my ng-click functionality, which I really want to get away from:

Current Implementation:

```
<button ... ng-click="confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this foo?, 'delete', foo)">Delete</button>

var confirmModule = angular.module('confirm', []);

confirmModule.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.confirm = function(text, func, obj) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('confirm', func, obj, text);
    };
});

confirmModule.directive('confirmBox', function($parse) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: myModalTemplate,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.hide();
            var noBtn = element.find("[name='no']");
            noBtn.bind("click", function() {
                element.hide();
            });
            scope.$on("confirm", function(event, func, obj, text) {
                var yesBtn = element.find("[name='yes']");
                element.show();
                yesBtn.unbind("click").bind("click", function() {
                    scope[func](obj);
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Anyone have any ideas? I started by adding the directive for the button and then unbinding the click event so `ng-click` doesn't fire. Then I am left with the string `'delete(foo)'` from the `ng-click` attribute that I can execute with `$parse(attrs.ngClick)(scope)`, but I don't know how to tie that to the separate directives button click.

Edit: Here is a fiddle with my current attempt at implementation. The problem is the variable being passed in to the function is always undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/UCtbj/2/

Edit2: Updated implementation, however I don't particularly like how it links the two directives together by targetting the other directives elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/UCtbj/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a repo for this functionality. It wraps the ui-bootstrap modal to produce a confirmation box. It is customizable and easily integrated into any application.

Here is the link to the GitHub: https://github.com/Schlogen/angular-confirm

Example Usages:

As a directive:

```
 <button type="button" ng-click="delete()" confirm-if="checked" confirm="Are you sure, {{name}}?">Delete</button>
```

As a service:

```
$confirm({text: 'Are you sure you want to delete?'})
  .then(function() {
    $scope.deletedConfirm = 'Deleted';
  });
```

Comment: This one is pretty close but sort of jumps because it alters the scroll instead of doing an overlay.

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me that you're trying to do things the jQuery way from within the directive. However, what you want is as simple as pulling in the UI-Bootstrap directive for confirming actions.  http://plnkr.co/edit/JhfAF1?p=preview

Comment: The problem with this is that it requires you to put this dialog code in each function you want it to show. It really has nothing to do with the business logic of the application so imo, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: It seems that angular UI has been refactored and the $dialog service has been removed and you can use messagebox functionality as indicated in the plunker anymore. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468127/where-is-dialog-messagebox-in-angular-ui

Comment: I could refactor it to use the $modal service in my confirm directive. I still don't want to use $modal in my controller - its view logic so doesn't belong there.

Comment: is there a way to use ONLY the UI-BS part of the code and not having to load the rest?

Answer (score 3):

First simple service for modal windows:

```
app.service('ConfirmService', function($modal) {
  var service = {};
  service.open = function (text, onOk) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalConfirmCtrl',
      resolve: {
        text: function () {
          return text;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      onOk();
    }, function () {
    });
  };

  return service;
})

app.controller('ModalConfirmCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, text) {

  $scope.text = text;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close(true);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Then simple directive that uses it:

```
app.directive('confirm', function(ConfirmService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            eventHandler: '&ngClick'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
          element.unbind("click");
          element.bind("click", function(e) {
            ConfirmService.open(attrs.confirm, scope.eventHandler);
          });
        }
    }
});
```

And here u go:

```
<button ng-click="test(12)" confirm='Are you sure?'>Button</button>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LOZOnsVyx3JU5XoKYn74?p=preview

Comment: This one looks cleaner than mine. Does this one still need the && confirm test within ng-click? Or is it binded somehow?

Comment: is there a way to not use the ui-bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

To allow a button to be marked up like

```
<button type="button" ng-click="deleteItem(drink)" ng-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete '{{drink.name}}'">Delete</button>
```

You can write a directive that

- Intercepts the click event before `ngClick`'s click handler can run
- Opens a dialog (using `$modal` and not the removed `$dialog`)
- On `close` of the dialog (which is treated as a success) run the function specified by the `ngClick` attribute on the element.

Basing the code on [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17156648/1319998), you can do this as follows:

```
app.directive('ngConfirm', function($modal, $parse) {
  return {
    // So the link function is run before ngClick's, which has priority 0
    priority: -1,

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function(e) {
        // Don't run ngClick's handler
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'ng-confirm-template',
          controller: 'ngConfirmController',
          resolve: {
            message: function() {
              return attrs.ngConfirm;
            }
          }
        }).result.then(function() {
          // Pass original click as '$event', just like ngClick
          $parse(attrs.ngClick)(scope, {$event: e});
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

which needs a simple controller:

```
app.controller('ngConfirmController', function($scope, $modalInstance, message) {
  $scope.message = message;

  $scope.yes = function() {
    $modalInstance.close();
  };

  $scope.no = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss();
  };
});
```

and template for the dialog:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ng-confirm-template">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-link pull-left" ng-click="no()">No</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="yes()">Yes</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

You can see this running at http://plnkr.co/edit/Gm9lFsGb099w6kCMQoVY?p=preview

Edit: changed plunker link to example without scrollbar appearing/disappearing on display of the dialog

Comment: This implementation has the same idea as mine, however I can see some issues with it - see my answer.

Comment: @JamesKleeh What are the issues?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice directive for that.That is `ngBootbox`. Check it out.

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"
        ng-bootbox-title="A cool title!"
        ng-bootbox-custom-dialog="Some custom text"
        ng-bootbox-buttons="customDialogButtons"
        ng-bootbox-class-name="some-class">
    Custom dialog
</button>

<script>
    $scope.customDialogButtons = {
        warning: {
            label: "Warning!",
            className: "btn-warning",
            callback: function() { $scope.addAction('Warning', false); }
        },
        success: {
            label: "Success!",
            className: "btn-success",
            callback: function() { $scope.addAction('Success!', true) }
        },
        danger: {
            label: "Danger!",
            className: "btn-danger",
            callback: function() { $scope.addAction('Danger!', false) }
        },
        main: {
            label: "Click ME!",
            className: "btn-primary",
            callback: function() { $scope.addAction('Main...!', true) }
        }
    };
    </script>
```

**[Demo](http://eriktufvesson.github.io/ngbootbox/)**

**[ngBootbox](https://github.com/eriktufvesson/ngBootbox)**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the one I ended up going with

1) Create a service for the dialog

```
app.service('dialogModal', [
    '$modal', function($modal) {
    return function(message, title, okButton, cancelButton) {

      okButton = okButton === false ? false : (okButton || 'Yes');
      cancelButton = cancelButton === false ? false : (cancelButton || 'No');

      var modalInstance = $modal.open({        
        templateUrl: '/templates/deletePrompt.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
          settings: function() {
            return {
              modalTitle: title,
              modalBody: message,
              okButton: okButton,
              cancelButton: cancelButton
            };
          }
        }
      });
      // return the modal instance
      return modalInstance;
    }
  }
]);
```

2) Create a controller and pass the model instance in it

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, settings) {

  angular.extend($scope, settings);

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close(true);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

3) included the link into the header to take on default styling

```
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

4) overwrote the styling in my own css

5) Here is my delete prompt template

```
<div id="overlayClearMainDiv" class="dialog-modal">
  <div id="overlayClearText">
    <span>{{modalBody}}</span>
  </div>
  <div id="overlayClearButton">
    <button id="overlayClearYesButton" class="confirmButton" type="button" ng-click="ok()" ng-show="okButton">{{okButton}}</button> 
    <button class="confirmButton-white" ng-click="cancel()" ng-show="cancelButton">{{cancelButton}}</button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick one for you - http://plnkr.co/edit/YklthDZcknmvMjU5A6pe?p=preview

So basically if you are interested in showing a modal dialog once a user clicks on let's say, a button there's no need to make it difficult.
All you need is a simple directive that encapsulate `$modal` service found in ui-bootstrap.

In my simple example I just pass in a string representing a message and then defining a `on-confirm` attribute that my directive invokes once the user confirms. Invoking the function itself leverages the awesomeness of `$parse` to resolve the expression and once resolved, invoke it with the scope.

Nice and clear and here's how it looks like.

**View**

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">

    <input type="button" value="Delete" 
           confirm="'Are you sure you want to delete me?'" on-confirm="delete()" />



    <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Confirm</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>The world won't be a better place if you delete me.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

 </body>
```

**Controller / Directive**

```
angular
    .module('App', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.delete = function(){
            alert('Woho, Im deleted!');
        };
    }])
    .directive('confirm', ['$modal', '$parse', function($modal, $parse){
        return {
            link: function(scope, el, attr){
              el.bind('click', function(){
                var instance = $modal.open({
                  templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                  controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance', modalController]
                });

                instance.result.then(function(){
                  // close - action!
                  $parse(attr.onConfirm)(scope);
                },function(){
                  // dimisss - do nothing
                });
              });
            }
        };

        function modalController(modalScope, $modalInstance){
            modalScope.ok = function(){
                modalInstance.close();
            };
            modalScope.cancel = function(){
                modalInstance.dismiss();
            };
        }
    }]);
```