# Where is $dialog.messageBox() in Angular UI?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I could not find `$dialog` service in AngularUI and I tried to explore a simple `messageBox()` to create a confirmation dialog box using `$modal`. Could not find that either.

Can somebody suggest me how to create a simple dialog (say for delete confirmation) using AngularJS / AngularUI?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `$dialog` service was refactored into `$modal` for version [0.6.0](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) of ui-bootstrap. The functionality from `$dialog` should still be available, just through `$modal` instead.

According to the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), you should make sure you have included **bootstrap's css** and **angular.js** in your page as well as **bootstrap-ui's JS**, which you can download from the doc site. I'd look at the 'create your own' link if you only need to use the `$modal` service and not the other directives.

If these files are included in your page, then make sure the definition of your angular module includes `ui.bootstrap` as a dependency. e.g.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

If this is done then you should be able to inject the `$modal` service within your module, like you would with any other service.

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.openModal = function() {
       // Can use $modal service as per examples in doc page
    };
});
```

As for solid examples, the docs page has great examples on the page and in plunker (so you can play with them) for each of their services and directives. I would like to link to the plunker here, but I don't seem able to.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. $dialog had a method named messageBox(), which is not present with $modal service. I just want to create a simple confirmation box, is there any other way except using $modal.open()?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this doesn't exist anymore and there is an [open issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/996) about adding a migration guide. One of the [comments](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/996#issuecomment-25388935) has an example service using `$modal` that may do what you want, otherwise you would need to downgrade bootstrap-ui or write your own service with the same functionality.