# How to inject $dialog into existing angularjs page controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create simple pop-up dialog in AngularJS using bootstrap-ui's $dialog directive.

I get $dialog undefined, when I try to inject into my controller. Can someone provide hint on "How to properly inject $dialog" into the following design and invoke it to create a pop-up dialog?

Thanks in advance

index.js:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['myapp.core','myapp.templates','ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap',
  'angularChart', 'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect', 'smart-table', 'angularModalService']);
```

Page Controller:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myapp').controller('Page3Controller', Page3Controller);
  function Page3Controller(
    $scope,
    $dialog, // undefined
    Page3Service,
    Utility) {
```

Comment: It is `$modal`, not `$dialog`.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468127/where-is-dialog-messagebox-in-angular-ui) says,
The `$dialog` service was refactored into `$modal` for version [0.6.0](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) of `ui-bootstrap`. The functionality from `$dialog` should still be available, just through `$modal` instead.

inject the `$modal` service within your module and it should work. Read the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

So, to edit your code,

```
 (function() {
      'use strict';
      angular.module('myapp').controller('Page3Controller', Page3Controller);
      function Page3Controller(
        $scope,
        $modal, // now do with it whatever you want, refer to the docs for detailed change
        Page3Service,
        Utility) {
```

Please check if it is working this way.

Comment: I can inject $modal, however when I try to follow the suggestion from the docs I get error stating   'ModalInstanceCtrl' not defined. I have it in a separate .js file instanceControl.js file.

Comment: You should import the file holding this second cotnroller (for example loading it via <script> tag in your index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
(function(){
    angular.module("myApp").controller("Page3Controller", ["$scope", 
        "$dialog", "Page3Service", "Utility", Page3Controller]);

        function Page3Controller($scope, $dialog, Page3Service, Utility){
            $dialog.whatEverYouNeedToDo();

        }
});
```